# Can I get a notification when a user writes a post on his wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am new to the FB platform. So far I played with PHP and I managed to fetch user data and to post a comment to one post.

I can't seem to find any way to be notified when a specific user makes a new post or comment.

I would like to have an event triggered when a user writes a new post on his facebook wall.

The obvious solution is to make requests every one minute or so and manually check the data for new changes. But I feel this would be a very clumsy and bandwidth expensive way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You can get every notification of any user by adding the user to a list, in facebook, the lists are a way to manage your contacts (friends), so, let's say, you want to receive a notification of X user when he update his status, when he uploads a photo/video, when he goes from single to a relationship, etc. (stay updated about X user/users) you simply need to add them to your "Best friends" smart-list. Check it out.

https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=10150278932602131

Comment: thank you. Can I add that functionality to my app? I'm not sure what privileges I need to request from the user and how exactly the lists feature comes into play - it appears to be related to other people, not the person using my app.